# Python get the items in a list from a dictionary within a list

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list that contains dictionaries. Each dictionary has a list for the value.I have a dictionary that contains a list for the values.

```
mylist = {'prop3': ['ss']}, {'mvpd': ['asdf', 'wefef']}, {'app_name': ['d']}
```

I need a way to get the lists inside each dictionary. I will know which key of the dictionary I want to grab the list from.

For example. With the above structure I want to be able to just pull out 'asdf', 'wefef' from the mvpd key.

Comment: This data structure doesn't allow you to lookup key values without iterating though the list because you don't know which element of the list has the correct key. If these are unique keys, it should really be a single dict, not a list of dicts.

Comment: I updated my code. It doesn't need to be in a list. So it is just a dictionary now.

Comment: @Halloween a valid dict would look like: `d = {'prop3': ['ss'], 'mvpd': ['asdf', 'wefef'], 'app_name': ['d']}`. Then getting that list is as easy as `d['mvpd']`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let:

```
mylist = [{'prop3': ['ss']}, {'mvpd': ['asdf', 'wefef']}, {'app_name': ['d']}]
```

and the key you require is:

```
key = 'mvpd'
```

We'll now check if the key exists in each item of the list:

```
[i[key] for i in mylist if key in i]
```

gives:

```
[['asdf', 'wefef']]
```

---

You your list dictionaries have a unique value:

```
for i in mylist:
    if key in i:
        res = i[key]
```

but if two dictionaries can have the same key:

```
res = []
for i in mylist:
    if key in i:
        res.append([key])
```